# Help with left factoring a grammar to remove left recursion

Tags: antlr, grammar, left-recursion

I have a small custom scripting language, and I am trying to update it to allow boolean expressions such as `a > 2` and `a > 2 and (b < 3 or c > 5)`.  It's the parenthetical expressions that I am having trouble with here.

Here is a (edited since the original post based on the answer from @Bart Kiers) full grammar that exhibits the problem.  This is a pared-down version of my actual grammar, but the problem occurs here too.

```
grammar test;


options {
    language = 'JavaScript'; 
    output = AST;
} 


statement 
    :   value_assignment_statement  
        EOF
    ;


value_assignment_statement 
    :   IDENT
        '='
        expression                      
    ;

value_expression 
    :   value_list_expression           
    |   IDENT                           
    ;


value_list_expression 
    :   value_enumerated_list       
    ;


value_enumerated_list : '{' unary+ '}'
    ;



term 
    :   LPAREN expression RPAREN        
    |   INTEGER                         
    |   value_expression                
    ;

unary : ( '+' | '-' )* term
    ;

mult :  unary ( ('*' | '/') unary)*
    ;

expression : mult ( ('+' | '-') mult )*
    ;


boolean 
    :   boolean_expression
        EOF
    ;

boolean_expression
    :   boolean_or_expression
    ;

boolean_or_expression 
    :   boolean_and_expression (OR boolean_and_expression)*
    ;

boolean_and_expression 
    :   boolean_rel_expression (AND boolean_rel_expression)*
    ;

boolean_rel_expression
    :   boolean_neg_expression relational_operator boolean_neg_expression
    ;

boolean_neg_expression 
    :   (NOT)? atom
    ;

atom
    :   LPAREN boolean_expression RPAREN
    //| expression
    ;


relational_operator : '=' | '>' | '<';


LPAREN      :   '(';
RPAREN      :   ')';
AND         :   'and';
OR          :   'or';
NOT         :   'not';
IDENT       :   LETTER LETTER+;
INTEGER     :   DIGIT+;
WS          :   (' ' | '\n' | '\r' | '\t')+     { $channel = HIDDEN; };

fragment DIGIT      : '0'..'9';
fragment LETTER     : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
```

My attempt to accommodate parenthetical boolean expressions such as `a > 2 or (b < 3)` is in the commented-out line in the `atom` rule.  When I uncomment this line and include it in the grammar, ANTLR gives me this error:

> [fatal] rule atom has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.

I would like to address this by removing the recursion, but I can't seem to make the transition from the [Wikipedia description on how to remove left recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) to my own stuff.

In using this grammar, I want sometimes to use `statement` as a root with input such as `abc = 2 + 3`, which assigns a value to a variable named abc. Other times I want to use the grammar to evaluate an expression with `boolean` as the root with input such as `abc > 3 and (xyz < 5 or xyz > 10)`. When I tried to use @Bart's answer as a model, it worked fine until I tried to merge the parts of the grammar used by `statement` with the parts used by `boolean`.  They should both be able to use an `expression`, but that's where I'm stuck with this left recursion error.

So, how can I both handle parentheses and avoid the left recursion problem?

Comment: Does your `expression` symbol have a rule for parenthesized expressions?

Comment: @larsmans: It can represent parenthetical expressions that evaluate to a number, such as `(3 + x) * 2` but doesn't accommodate the boolean evaluations I am doing now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Boolean expressions are just the same as the additive- and multiplicative expression, and should therefore not be separated from them. Here's how to account for all types of expressions:

```
grammar test;

parse
  :  expression EOF
  ;

expression 
  :  or
  ;

or
  :  and (OR and)*
  ;

and
  :  rel (AND rel)*
  ;

rel
  :  add (('=' | '>' | '<') add)*
  ;

add
  :  mult (('+' | '-') mult)*
  ;

mult
  :  unary (('*' | '/') unary)*
  ;

unary 
  :  '-' term
  |  '+' term
  |  NOT term
  |  term
  ;

term 
  :  INTEGER  
  |  IDENT       
  |  list
  |  '(' expression ')'
  ;

list 
  :  '{' (expression (',' expression)*)? '}'
  ;

AND     :  'and';
OR      :  'or';
NOT     :  'not';
IDENT   :  LETTER LETTER*;
INTEGER :  DIGIT+;
WS      :  (' ' | '\n' | '\r' | '\t')+  { $channel = HIDDEN; };

fragment DIGIT   : '0'..'9';
fragment LETTER  : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
```

which will parse the example input:

```
abc > 3 and (xyz < 5 or xyz > {1, 2, 3})
```

into the following parse tree:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This makes sense to me, when used in isolation.  I now see that the problem lies in how this boolean-related stuff interacts with the other expression-based stuff in my grammar. I have edited my original post with a subset of my real grammar that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @Chris, see my revised answer.

Comment: thanks so much for the update. The main reason I thought I wanted them separate is that in certain contexts I want the input to only be able to support some sort of relational comparison. In the grammar you have, there's only one root and `a + 3` is always going to be valid input, but sometimes I don't want it to be. So, in my use case, I would say that booleans are *not* the same as additive/multiplicative expressions as you suggest at the beginning of your answer. Is there some reason that it's dumb to think of them as I'm trying to?

Comment: @Chris, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. But can't you just do it as I suggest (or very similar) and while evaluating (walking over the AST), perform certain checks to see if certain expressions are allowed at a specific location in the AST. If this isn't an option for you, please edit your original question (or post a new one) and give a couple of example input sources that show the problem. Good luck.